# Php:Fatal error: call to unrefined function mqsql_real_escape_string ($_POST ['username']);

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, fatal-error

below code and the error has given

```
$Username =mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['Username']);

 fatal error:call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_string ()
```

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: What is your current php version and your mysql connection string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your connection string from mysql to mysqli

```
 // connection string
 $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "mpassword", "database") or die($link);

$Username= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Username']);
```